# Vuforia Engine AR not visible in package manager in Unity 2020

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new to unity and vuforia to complete a project i need vuforia engine AR in package manager, the steps shown in the video for unity are **Window->Package Manager -> All Packages ->Vuforia Engine AR**.
I couldn't access the AllPackages menu so someone suggested that i preview all the packages,i used player setting and selected preview packages, for all the other packages, this doesn't work either.

So i downloaded the vuforia sdk form the site, and i imported all of them into the project,it still didn't show me anything in the GameObject window, i tried to search for the required components like ARCamera and GroundPlaneFinder in the file i imported and they weren't in there.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, i figured it out, apparently in versions above 2020 in unity it is labelled as vuforia engine  to access it go to window->package manager-> my assets->vuforia engine-> import(these were my settings don't know if it changes from version to version)

Be careful and don't try to import it in middle of a project though apparently it needs to be initialized/imported at the start of the project to avoid dependencies. you can create your project later.